# Error When Using CheckBoxFor in MVC with VB

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, checkboxfor

I'm trying to create a checkbox with the following code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.PotentialDishmachineProducts)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.PotentialDishmachineProducts)
```

But, it keeps throwing up the error:

"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Here's the property in the model:

```
Public Property PotentialDishmachineProducts As String
```

It is not tied into a database or anything.  Any ideas how to get this checkbox to work?  Btw, if it's not obvious, I am brand new to MVC and VB.

Thanks!!

Comment: Figured it out.  Switched As String to As Boolean.

Comment: You should either answer the question yourself below or just delete the question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched `As String` to `As Boolean`.